# Is there any TTS (Text To Speech) engine for Cantonese?

Tags: voice, text-to-speech, text-to-speech-voices, speech

I am looking for TTS (Text To Speech) engine for Cantonese.

Comment: Are you interested in Hong Kong Cantonese, or Canton Cantonese?  Although these two are mostly similar, there are some key differences (in addition to the accents).

Comment: Uhm.. anyone care to explain the downvotes?

Comment: @Randolf Richardson : They are both OK !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a web site here that can do this (they support a number of Mandarin voices, one of which uses a Cantonese dialect; *please also note that the "Taiwanese" voice listed is actually speaking Mandarin rather than the local Taiwanese dialect {which is not the same as Mandarin despite some misunderstanding by many foreigners that it is}*):

SitePal - Text to speech
  http://www.oddcast.com/home/demos/tts/tts_example.php?sitepal

You can enter the following Chinese characters (which are a rough translation of a William Shakespear quotation, which I've also included for your convenience):

- 溢出的良好轉換壞。
- An overflow of good converts to bad.

Comment: It's good but I need a engine to be installed on Windows in order to use it in Lingoes - a dictionary.

Comment: Oh, then what you need to mention in your question somewhere is that you "need text-to-speech software that doesn't require constant access to the internet, and is in the form of a self-contained/stand-alone program."

Comment: Hm... Maybe you're right. It's a package can be installed same as Microsoft Anna voiced in Windows 7.